# splitting the gvim editor window horizontally

Tags: editors, gvim

In gvim editor how to split the editor window horizontally? so that includes two files and can see simultaneously
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**From command line:**

open specified files as horizontal splits

```
gvim -o report.log power.log area.log
```

open specified files as vertical splits

```
gvim -O report.log power.log area.log
```

**Within the editor**

open file for editing in new horizontal split screen

```
:split filename
:sp filename
```

open file for editing in new vertical split screen

```
:vsplit filename
:vs filename
```

Check out `:h windows.txt` for more help

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl+W, S (upper case) for horizontal splitting

Comment: it got splitted but i want two different files to be viewed in splitted windows.

Comment: you don't, its a shortcut key.

Comment: then to view two different files in the same window by splitting then what should i do?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/486535/410599

Comment: @SruthiChowdavarapu, you execute `:e anotherfilename` in one half of the split.